# Harry Potter: Bubotuber Pus vs. Undiluted Bubotuber Pus

Tags: harry-potter

It is said in the 4th Harry Potter than Bubotuber pus is used to clear up acne. However when Hermione receives it in her hate mail, it is described by Ron as "undiluted" and causes her hands to swell up as if she were wearing gloves.

What is the difference? Surely anything that causes someone's hands to do that wouldn't want to put it on their face right?

Comment: Did you look up "diluted"?

Comment: Yes and that's what confused me. Because if anything "diluted" makes things weaker or more watered down

Comment: Exactly. At its strongest, (undiluted) bubotuber pus causes damage. But diluted (watered down), it has some effect but not enough to do damage.

Comment: Oh duh I answered my own question

Comment: For a real-world example, you wouldn't want to drink concentrated phosphoric acid, but diluted with water, sugar, and carbonation, it provides a nice tang to your soda.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_dose_makes_the_poison

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To ***dilute*** is to '*reduce the concentration of a substance by adding water or another similar solvent*'.

It's pretty clear that primary ingredients in Bubotuber Pus Acne Medication (and other '[beautifying creams](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Beautification_Potion)') is raw bubotuber pus along with other modifiers. In its raw and *undiluted* form it appears to be rather more dangerous and unsuited for topical application.

As a matter of interest, the active ingredient in muggle acne cream; [Benzyl Peroxide](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Benzoyl_peroxide) has exactly the same problem, especially at concentrations above 10%. At 100% ("undiluted"), it's [downright dangerous](https://www.quora.com/Is-it-possible-to-make-a-100-benzoyl-peroxide-cream-or-wash-Would-it-be-harmful-to-the-skin-if-used).

> Benzoyl peroxide commonly causes initial dryness and sometimes
>   irritation, although the skin develops tolerance after a week or so. A
>   small percentage of people are much more sensitive to it and liable to
>   suffer burning, itching, crusting, and possibly swelling.